# Ruby, pack encoding (ASCII-8BIT that cannot be converted to UTF-8)

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8

```
puts "C3A9".lines.to_a.pack('H*').encoding
```

results in

```
ASCII-8BIT
```

but I prefer this text in UTF-8. But

```
"C3A9".lines.to_a.pack('H*').encode("UTF-8")
```

results in

```
`encode': "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
```

why? How can I convert it to UTF-8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way. If you have URI encoded data like this:

```
%C5%BBaba
```

Then you should use [`URI.unescape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-unescape) to decode it:

```
1.9.2-head :004 > URI.unescape('%C5%BBaba')
 => "Żaba"
```

If that doesn't work then force the encoding to UTF-8:

```
1.9.2-head :004 > URI.unescape('%C5%BBaba').force_encoding('utf-8')
 => "Żaba"
```

Comment: Where did this magic `URI`class come from? `open-uri`? `rails`? `CGI.rb`?

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh: `require 'uri'`

Comment: And again, related encoding problem ("URI.unescape crashes as it is trying to convert “%C3%9Fą” to “ßą”"): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328086/uri-unescape-crashes-as-it-is-trying-to-convert-c39fa-to-ssa Maybe somebody knows what is happening?

Answer (score 4):

`ASCII-8bit` is a pretend encoding native to Ruby. It has an alias to `BINARY`, and it is just that. `ASCII-8bit` is not a character encoding, but rather a way of saying that a string is binary data and not to be processed like text. Because `pack`/`unpack` functions are designed to operate on binary data, you should never assume that is returned is printable under any encoding unless the ENTIRE pack string is made up of character derivatives. If you clarify what the overall goal is, maybe we could give you a better solution.

---

If you isolate a hex UTF-8 code into a variable, say `code` which is a string of the hexadecimal format minus percent sign:

```
utf_char=[code.to_i(16)].pack("U")
```

Combine these with the rest of the string, you can make your string.

Comment: I receive text in UTF-8, as hex: "%C5%BB" instead of "Ż" (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z WITH DOT ABOVE). I discovered that <"test.txt", "C5BB".lines.to_a.pack('H*')> produces "Ż" on writing to file, but unfortunately I was unable to use results of this conversion inside application, due to ASCII-8bit problem (I based this thing on http://dailyhacking.posterous.com/working-with-hexadecimal-and-binary-in-ruby )

Comment: So what does the exact hex string look like?

Comment: "%C5%BBaba" is "Żaba", only "strange" letters are written using hex

Comment: So your percent sign indicates a two character hex number?

Comment: Yes, and % is used only before hex code, so I need way to convert utf-8 saved as hex to utf-8

Comment: Can you change your above code to using `force_encoding` instead of `encode`? It may work.