# URI.unescape crashes as it is trying to convert "%C3%9Fą" to "ßą"

Tags: ruby, encoding, character-encoding, crash, uri

I am using  [URI.unescape](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-unescape) to unescape text, unfortunately I run into weird error:

```
 # encoding: utf-8
 require('uri')
 URI.unescape("%C3%9Fą")
```

results in

```
 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:331:in `gsub': incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:331:in `unescape'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:649:in `unescape'
    from exe/fail.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation of `URI.unescape` is broken for non-ASCII inputs. The [1.9.3 version](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_1_9_3/lib/uri/common.rb#L330) looks like this:

```
def unescape(str, escaped = @regexp[:ESCAPED])
  str.gsub(escaped) { [$&[1, 2].hex].pack('C') }.force_encoding(str.encoding)
end
```

The regex in use is `/%[a-fA-F\d]{2}/`. So it goes through the string looking for a percent sign followed by two hex digits; in the block `$&` will be the matched text ('%C3' for example) and `$&[1,2]` be the matched text without the leading percent sign (`'C3'`). Then we call [`String#hex`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-hex) to convert that hexadecimal number to a Fixnum (`195`) and wrap it in an Array (`[195]`) so that we can use [`Array#pack`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-pack) to do the byte mangling for us. The problem is that `pack` gives us a single binary byte:

```
> puts [195].pack('C').encoding
ASCII-8BIT
```

The ASCII-8BIT encoding is also known as "binary" (i.e. plain bytes with no particular encoding). Then the block returns that byte and [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) tries to insert into the UTF-8 encoded copy of `str` that `gsub` is working on and you get your error:

> incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)

because you can't (in general) just stuff binary bytes into a UTF-8 string; you can often get away with it:

```
URI.unescape("%C3%9F")         # Works
URI.unescape("%C3µ")           # Fails
URI.unescape("µ")              # Works, but nothing to gsub here
URI.unescape("%C3%9Fµ")        # Fails
URI.unescape("%C3%9Fpancakes") # Works
```

Things start falling apart once you start mixing non-ASCII data into your URL encoded string.

One simple fix is to switch the string to binary before try to decode it:

```
def unescape(str, escaped = @regexp[:ESCAPED])
  encoding = str.encoding
  str = str.dup.force_encoding('binary')
  str.gsub(escaped) { [$&[1, 2].hex].pack('C') }.force_encoding(encoding)
end
```

Another option is to push the `force_encoding` into the block:

```
def unescape(str, escaped = @regexp[:ESCAPED])
  str.gsub(escaped) { [$&[1, 2].hex].pack('C').force_encoding(encoding) }
end
```

I'm not sure why the `gsub` fails in some cases but succeeds in others.

Comment: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/ - is it a correct place to report bugs in standard ruby library?

Answer (score 9):

Don't know why but you can use `CGI.unescape` method:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require 'cgi'
CGI.unescape("%C3%9Fą")
```

Comment: Argh, next problem - is it possible to stop it from converting to characters invalid in UTF-8 (it converted "%EA%E6" to \xEA\xE6 characters what crashes gsub with "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8")

Comment: Ive replaced URI.escape with CGI.escape in my ruby script and it helped thx

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Vasiliy's answer that suggests using `CGI.unescape`:

As of Ruby 2.5.0, `URI.unescape` is obsolete.

See https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-unescape.

"This method is obsolete and should not be used. Instead, use CGI.unescape, URI.decode_www_form or URI.decode_www_form_component depending on your specific use case."